# Successive Ajax Calls Have Data Swapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following situation.

I have the following method to make ajax calls to load json data.

```
// Generic loadJSON
function loadJSON(method, url, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            callback(json);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I have the following function setup to load the json data

```
    loadJSON('GET', 'url/Scripts/data.json?callback=?', function (response)
{
    jsonData = response;
    var returnHighest = getHighestValue("Return");
    var riskHighest = getHighestValue("Risk");
    var returnLowest = getLowestValue("Return");
    var riskLowest = getLowestValue("Risk");
    gauge.max = returnHighest / 100;
    gauge.min = returnLowest / 100;
    gauge2.max = riskHighest / 100;
    gauge2.min = riskLowest / 100;
    //gaugeInput.max = returnHighest / 100;
    // gaugeInput.min = returnLowest / 100;
    // gauge2Input.max = riskHighest / 100;
    //gauge2Input.min = riskLowest / 100;
    loadJSON('GET', 'url/Scripts/data2.json?callback=?', function (response)
    {
        jsonData2 = response;
        CalculateRiskReturnCorrelation();
        gauge.value = GetReturn() / 100;
        $('#returnValue').html("" + (gauge.value*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
        gauge2.value = GetRisk() / 100;
        $('#riskValue').html("" + (gauge2.value * 100).toFixed(2) + "%");
        CalculateRiskReturnCorrelation();
    });

    // Loads JSON to change the alternative fund data
    loadJSON('GET', 'url/Scripts/data3.json?callback=?', function (response) {
        jsonData3 = response;
        // Set gloabl vairables
        alternativeColor = jsonData3.Fund1.Color;
        alternativeName = jsonData3.Fund1.Name;
        alternativeMax = jsonData3.Fund1.Max;
        // Handle possible height change of label
        $('#alternatives-text').html(alternativeName);
        var newTopPos = (($('#alternatives-text').height() - $('#slider_alternatives').height()) / 2) + $('#alternatives-text').position().top;
        $('#alternatives-text').css({ top: newTopPos + "px" });
        $('#slider_alternatives').css({ background: alternativeColor });
        $('#slider_alternatives').slider('option', { min: 0, max: alternativeMax });
        var chart = $('#pie').highcharts();
        chart.series[0].addPoint({ name: alternativeName, y: 0, color: alternativeColor, style: { fontSize: "15px", "text-align": "right" } });
        alternativesSet = true;

    });
});
```

Now sometimes this loads correctly and sometimes the third JSON call loads the data from the second json call. Not sure how this is possible since they have different urls and their response functions are totally different and self contained. The second json call gets a success message and an error all at once.

It seems to be a timing issue since it works sometimes, but I don't see how the responses are getting crossed up. Any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: You're giving them the same `jsonpCallback` name?

Comment: That would be it. Sometimes those obvious things are the ones that are he hardest to spot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think one call is returning before another in terms of timing. You need to wait for each one to return before starting the next one in this scenario. Try setting the ajax calls to 'async: false' like this:

```
// Generic loadJSON
function loadJSON(method, url, callback)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function (json) {
        callback(json);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. the problem was I had the same jsonpCallback names for all three. That allowed the third call to pull the results of the second call.